# How can I get the URL of an answer among the long list of answers of a question?

Tags: support, answers, hyperlinks

I need to refer to a specific answer but I don't know how to or whether it is available. Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below the text of the answer there is a gray "link" that will link directly to that answer.

[image]

Comment: +1 The link has been renamed "share" but this is still a very helpful answer!